# need to remove folder via htaccess rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently have an URLs that are looking like this:

```
www.mysite.com/x/page-name1.php 
www.mysite.com/xxx/page-name2.php
```

Where x & xxx's are digits.

but I need it to look like this:

```
www.mysite.com/page-name1.php
www.mysite.com/page-name2.php
```

I need an htaccess rule to do that thing. Any advice?

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I just asked like every one does here. Sorry for not providing source htaccess code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody still need's an answer.
Shame on community for not helping.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/$ /questions/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^xxx/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Replace the x's with your folder name. Make sure you clear your cache before testing.

Comment: Folder names are different. It could be 2015, and could be 9400 and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
ROptions +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^x/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```